# How do I send raw binary data via HTTP in node.js?

Tags: node.js, http, twitter

From a node.js back end, I need to send an HTTP message to a REST endpoint. The endpoint requires some parameters that it will expect to find in the HTTP message. Some of the parameters are simple enough, just requiring a number or a string as an argument. But one of the parameters is to be "the raw binary file content being uploaded" and this has puzzled me. As far as I understand, the parameters need to be gathered together into a string to put in the body of the HTTP request; How do I add raw binary data to a string? Obviously, for it to be in the string, it cannot be raw binary data; it needs to be encoded into characters.

The endpoint in question is the [Twitter media upload API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload-append). The "raw binary data" parameter is called `media`. Below is an incomplete code snippet showing the basic gist of what I've tried. Specifically, the line where I build the `requestBody` string. I don't believe it is anywhere near correct, because the endpoint is returning a "bad request" message.

```
var https = require("https");

var base64ImageData = /* (some base 64 string here) */;

var options = {
    host: "api.twitter.com",
    path: "/1.1/media/upload.json",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
};
var request = https.request(options, function(response) {});
var requestBody = "media_id=18283918294&media=" + Buffer.from(base64ImageData, "base64").toString("binary");
request.write(requestBody);
request.end();
```

Also worth noting, Twitter themselves note the following extremely confusing statement:

"When posting base64 encoded images, be sure to set the “Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64” **on the image part of the message**."

Source: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/uploading-media/media-best-practices

That might be part of the answer to my question, but what I don't understand is: **How do I apply different headers to different parts of the HTTP message?** Because apparently, the image data needs to have a Content-Transfer-Encoding header of "base64" while the rest of the HTTP message does not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I apply different headers to different parts of the HTTP message?

This is the point of the `multipart/form-data` content type. A multi-part message looks like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---foo---

---foo---
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datafile1"; filename="r.gif"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: image/gif

// data goes here
---foo---
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datafile2"; filename="g.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: image/png

// another file's data goes here
---foo---
```

You probably don't want to put all this together yourself. There are a bunch of good libraries for putting together complex POSTs. For example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data

Comment: Thank you, but this still leaves me baffled by the specific case of Twitter. Their documentation strongly implies the file data is just supposed to be provided in sort of a URL parameter format. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload-append. See the provided example there: `command=APPEND&media_id=123&segment_index=2&media_data=123` Can you speculate as to why that may be the case? Also just to be clear, in your example of a multi-part message, does all of that go in the body? Does the `boundary=--foo--` go in the Content-Type header?

Comment: @CircuitScholar those are query parameters, they are not part of the request body. When that format is used in the request body the content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: @CircuitScholar Twitter's docs have always been a bit shitty. Stop assuming implications - chances are if something's weird/nonsensical in their docs, it's just Twitter being Twitter. You don't send large multi-megabyte file data as a URL param.

Comment: (Side note: See the step-by-step guide at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/uploading-media/chunked-media-upload for chunked uploads, and make use of this bit: "To see full headers of the requests and responses when using twurl, use the -t option to enable trace mode.")